# Custom error page in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, custom-error-pages, server-error

I am using `ASP.Net MVC 3` and `EnterpriseLibrary` Data Access Layer for my application.

I am handling some of the data and business layer errors using `EnterpriseLibrary.Logging` and also using the default error handler of MVC like:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
       filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

In some cases I'm getting error page properly. But not in all the cases.

**Example:** If I request an Action with an invalid character, I'll get a server error instead of Custom Error Page.

I have requested as:
`http://localhost:50805/Home/Admin<` and I got an error

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (<).
```

How to display a Custom error page in such cases?

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own exception?
Try-catch your block and when the error is thrown you can redirect to an error page and/or display the exception details.